# Knockout radio button "checked" binding isn't working with jQuery Unobtrusive Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, unobtrusive-validation

I've got two radio button groups that are both connected by way of an identical KnockoutJS "checked" binding (like `checked: HasPets, checkedValue: true`).  The first one has an unobtrusive validation message that displays until the user has selected an answer.

The problem is that when I check a radio button on the question which does *not* have the unobtrusive validation, the `field-validation-error` does not disappear. Here's an example:

[image]

---

Is there anything that I can do to make this validation message disappear?

Also, here is a minimal example of the code used to reproduce the problem:

```
@model test_mvc_app.Models.TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Pets", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "petsForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HasPets)
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HasPets, true, new { @id = "HasPetsTrue", @data_bind = "checked: HasPets, checkedValue: true" })
        <label for="HasPetsTrue">Yes</label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HasPets, false, new { @id = "HasPetsFalse", @data_bind = "checked: HasPets, checkedValue: false" })
        <label for="HasPetsFalse">No</label>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HasPets)

    <hr/>

    <label>Just to clarify, you're a pet owner, right?</label>
    <div>
        <input data-bind="checked: HasPets, checkedValue: true" type="radio" value="true" >
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input data-bind="checked: HasPets, checkedValue: false" type="radio" value="false" >
        <label>No</label>
    </div>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var vm = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.HasPets = ko.observable(null);
        }

        var viewModel = new vm();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        // This makes the validation message appear by default.
        $("#petsForm").valid();
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**: Here is the *rendered* HTML:

```
<div>
    <input data-bind="checked: HasPets, checkedValue: true" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please answer this question." id="HasPetsTrue" name="HasPets" type="radio" value="true" aria-required="true" class="input-validation-error" aria-describedby="HasPets-error">
    <label for="HasPetsTrue">Yes</label>
    <input data-bind="checked: HasPets, checkedValue: false" id="HasPetsFalse" name="HasPets" type="radio" value="false" class="input-validation-error">
    <label for="HasPetsFalse">No</label>
</div>

<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="HasPets" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span id="HasPets-error" class="">Please answer this question.</span></span>
```

Comment: You might need a [computed function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) on the error message element e.g. `<span class="error" data-bind="visible: hasErrors()" />` In which the computed function knows whether any unobstrusive errors are unresolved or not. This is the approach I'd look into.

Comment: @JasonEvans That totally makes sense and I am making use of `visible` bindings, but I'm hoping that there is a more extensible solution (for a form with, like, a gazillion fields).

Comment: It looks like you're using the same set of ids for the inputs in both groups. That may not be causing the problem, but it is wrong. Can you post the HTML that MVC generates? It would be instructive to see what comes out.

Comment: @RoyJ Yes, I'll post the rendered HTML as well.  The id thing is a typo:  the HtmlHelpers automatically generate ids for these radio buttons, so I do not use the HtmlHelpers more than once in the code.  The problem persists after removing the duplicate ids.

Comment: I've made a dotnet fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k45dcE
but I don't know my way around MVC, so I'm just bumbling. The console gets errors about `$("#petsForm").valid();`, saying that there's no `valid` method. Can you get it to demonstrate your problem?